# Ayuda con pic16f877a

Tags: ccs, pic

Buenas tardes, mi problema es que estoy usando el pic 16f877a, para programar el software pic c y pickit2 para poder grabarlo, consigo leerlo y grabarlo correctamente pero al momento de ponerlo a funcionar no hace nada!! La verdad no se que pueda ser les agradecería cualquier aporte. Adjunto el montaje utilizado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
#include <16F877.h> //Archivo que incluye encabezados y definiciones 
#use delay (clock = 4000000) 
#FUSES NOWDT, XT 
#use standard_io(b) 
void main() { 
  while(1) { 
    output_low(PIN_B0); 
    delay_ms(100); 
    output_high(PIN_B0); 
    delay_ms(100); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Por favor, añade código a tu pregunta y el error que recibas. Sin ver nada de lo que has hecho es imposible saber dónde puede estar el problema.

Comment: Hola, no me da ningún error el problema es que no hace nada, el codigo que estoy usando es este:

Comment: en el pin del mclr no tengo conectado nada, solo tengo conectado en el pin rb0 un led y los pines de alimentación nada más.